# Is it possible to configure the 'message highlight pattern' for the TFS2015.2 build definition command line step?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

It is possible to configure the `Error message highlight pattern` and `Warning message highlight pattern` of the TFS2015.2 `Command Line` step?

For example, I may have the following build definition that runs a command line utility, say `gulp`, to perform some tasks such as code linting.

[image: Example build definition showing command line step]

The precise standard output (via `stdout`) of this utility would be varied depending on the precise lint tasks being run. For example, one tool for analysing TypeScript code and another tool for analysing Sass code.

Furthermore, the utility may:

- Write messages to the error stream (via `stderr`).
- Return a non-zero exit code.

Neither of the cases above are useful to me because in certain scenarios I don't want TFS to consider the build step has failed. I do however want warnings highlighted in the logs and build summary.

It would be useful to be able to teach the `Command Line` step about specific output message patterns that represent warnings and errors.

In the build logs for the `Command Line` step I see this:

[image: Build log extract showing message highlight pattern]

This seems to suggest a way to configure the line matching patterns for output that represents warnings and errors. However, I cannot find a way to configure these, hence my question.

I should point out that I'm aware there are other ways of achieving this:

- One way for example is via a targeted build step that is designed to wrap the command line utility. The built-in `Gulp` and `npm` steps for instance, or perhaps a custom authored step / extension.
- Another way is to emit [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) from a build script [as asked here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/573).

My question specifically relates to employing the built-in generic `Command Line` step directly when these options aren't available or desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, this can't be achieved by Command Line step directly. You may could ask a feature request in uservoice. The TFS administrator and PM will kindly review it.

> UserVoice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/

Comment: @matt did you create an issue on the uservoice site? ... I have the same problem

Comment: I suggest logging an issue or sending a pull request to: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues. It tends to result in faster responses than a uservoice item.