# Getting batch script task error highlighted in TFS Release Management

Tags: tfs

When deploying, the log lists blanks for Error and Warning highlight patterns:

```
Error message highlight pattern: 
Warning message highlight pattern:
```

Where can I set values for these so I can highlight my messages?

Comment: How did you want to highlight your message? Did you want to raise up it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such values can highlight your messages  for now in TFS.

However, you should be able to return warnings and errors from your script using [logging commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md). For example:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]Test warning"
Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Test error"
```

will return something like this:

[image]

Also take a look at this similar question: [Is it possible to configure the 'message highlight pattern' for the TFS2015.2 build definition command line step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918603/is-it-possible-to-configure-the-message-highlight-pattern-for-the-tfs2015-2-bu)

Comment: @Metaphor Of course, to invoke a logging command, simply emit the command via standard output.